# Creating accounts - What is this value?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, linked-accounts

*I don't know whether I can express everything here because, this looks like a strange bug. But, I can respond to comments for sure...*

I was involved in creating accounts. When I created my account in Christianity.SE, I logged in with Facebook accidentally. Since I won't be alive in facebook most of the time, I tried to log-in with gmail and finally removed my facebook login. It showed 101 - indicating "association OK"...

When I created my accounts in Linguistics and Bitcoin, my association was with some other Christianity profile. When I looked into it, my profile name was `a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae` with **my** smiley balls. But, I already have a profile. My linguistics and bitcoin profile showed 1 rep. score associated with this *bug* profile. There's an issue with this profile. There are **no** accounts, **no** logins, **no** `edit my about me` but I'm wondered how my gravatar got there without my gmail.

[image]

I can delete my other two profiles (I mean, I can see the `delete` button). But, I can't delete this one. Every time I create an account, it gets associated with this bug profile with **my** gmail ID (I tested with Biblical Hermeneutics.SE). Here's my profile at Bitcoin. You can see that I can edit everything around...

[image]

Now, you shall say, "Ohh.. Then, you can **delete** your profile". The problem is, I can delete the 1 rep. accounts without a problem. But, further creation of accounts lead to association with the bug profile - which is very rude..! What shall I do now?

---

Now, I saw my login preferential over Christianity.SE, and it had **NONE** (I don't know how this happened). How *can* an account exist without any login? So, I tried to add my gmail account. And, it shows:

[image]

If that's how the profiles are linked, then - all the 1 rep. profiles should be along with my Physics.SE & other accounts. Why does it stay alone somewhere? Moreover, this warning should've appeared when the bug profile was created. It didn't happen..!

Now, I logged into the bug profile and I can see that it uses my Gmail account. How can a 200+ rep. user have two different accounts (one with 1 rep.) with the same login..?

---

### Unexpected...

Once I logged into the bug profile, I deleted my 1 rep. account and it automatically logged out. Now, I reopened Christianity.SE. It said "Welcome, you're being redirected" - like somehow I've already logged in. It got into the 101 rep. account. Now, I thought the problem is gone, and went on to create my Bitcoin profile (which I deleted just now). Now, it welcomes me with a notification: *"Goto your user profile page"*. I think mods can see everything in the profile page. Since all the profiles above have gone now, this is [my new user profile](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/4605) over Bitcoin.

So, the conclusion - **I can't create further accounts with my Gmail and associate those...**

> I apologize to the community for deleting & creating profiles. But, I need to do it..! :(

---

### Figured out... (But, don't know "why" it happened..!)

I went to my Physics profile page. In my logins, there were ***none***..! I don't know (still can't figure out) how all of my logins were removed. I added my gmail and facebook login and now, I got the Bitcoin account associated automatically when I logged out & then in. Now, I can continue creating my accounts.

I suspect my logins should've been removed today *(Because 1 or 2 days ago, I cleared my firefox data (including login credentials) so that I logged in with my Google account again)*. But, I still can't figure out how all of my logins were erased from my profile.

Isn't it ridiculous that a profile worked for a few hours without any logins?

Comment: Thanks for the email address! The spam bots will be pleased!

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Ahh.., Whatever - My inbox is already full of spams :P

Comment: Spam bots have time to read images?